# Devexpress Reporting get Row data by click in it

Tags: c#, devexpress, reporting

I try get all values from the row(where was click) of XtraReport.
I don't know why, but xrTableRow1_PreviewClick and xrTable1_PreviewClick don't work. 
Works only xrTableCell4_PreviewClick. And through 'e.Brick.Text' I can get only value in cell.

```
private void xrTableCell1_PreviewClick(object sender, PreviewMouseEventArgs e)
{
  var tmp = e.Brick.Text;
}
```

If I try:

```
GetCurrentRow()
```

It gives only first row. It's not what I need. )

How can I get all values from the row where was click? Or how I can get Row Index where click was?
My report looks like in designer: 
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I expect you will need to trycast the row as one of your databoject to get at the full row of data

Comment: I've tried casts, but didn't find what I need. If someone knows what cast to what, please write it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no simple way to access the corresponding data row using brick methods. When all the required bricks are generated, the report does not refer to a data source anymore. In other words, bricks do now know about the underlying data. They just contain a text, image, or other controls.

The simplest way to accomplish this task is to handle the XRControl's BeforePrint event and pass the corresponding data object (DataRowView or a custom object) to the XRControl's Tag property:

```
private void xrLabel_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
    // Obtain the current label.
    XRLabel label = (XRLabel)sender;

    //Obtain the parent Report
    XtraReportBase parentReport = label.Report;

    //Get the data object
    object currentData = parentReport.GetCurrentRow();

    //Pass this object to Tag
    label.Tag = currentData;
}
```

After that, it's possible to access the data object via the e.Brick.Value property in the PreviewClick event handler.

Answer (score 1):

VB.net code to capture the values of any field in detail bank in preview mode.

```
Dim myo As Object
dim myacct as long

For i = 0 To e.Brick.Parent.Bricks.Count
Try
    myo = e.Brick.Parent.Bricks.Item(i) ' cant get name w/o this ???
    If myo.brickowner.name = "XrLabel14" Then  ' test for desired label
        myacct = myo.text   'capture the value
         Exit For
    End If
 Catch oerr As Exception
    'log error here
 End Try

Next
```